# Context sensitive generation in prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg, context-sensitive-grammar, dcg-semicontext

I am interested in generating elements of a context sensitive language as described by Chomsky, as described in [Chomsky Classification of Grammars](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/automata_theory/chomsky_classification_of_grammars.htm)
 under the section "Type - 1 Grammar".

(Basically, similar to a standard context-free grammar, but allowing multiple symbols on the left side of a production rule, including terminals).

I know about definite clause grammars in Prolog, but I don't see an obvious mapping between those and Chomsky's context sensitive languages.  Is there a "universal" way to use the DCG framework to describe production rules with multiple symbols on the left side, or do I need an ad hoc approach for each individual language?

Comment: There is an example of how to do this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar#Non-context-free_grammars) of all places, but for this to be a legitimate question on S.O., you have to have a concrete problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Of interest: [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) - Type 1 - Production rules - αAβ → αγβ

Answer (score 2):

Context on the right-hand side can be encoded directly using a semicontext:

```
nt1, "context" --> nt2, "context".
```

For context on the left-hand side, there is no obvious direct encoding.  Most often arguments to the non-terminals are used.